# Regex pattern to extract version number from string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract version number from string.

```
a string =  "Tale: The  Secrets 1.6"

b string=" The 34. Mask 1.6.98";
```

So for a version number is 1.6 and for b is 1.6.98

Comment: This all sort of depends on your defenition of version number right? 1.6 isn't a standard version number in c#, it'd be like 1.6.0.0.  What other kinds of version numbers do you plan to encounter?  Does a single digit count as a version number? Will your strings have digits other than version numbers that you need to account for? How about using a regular expression to extract any number followed by a period: (([0-9]+)\.?)+ and pass it to the Version class which can take a string in the constructor?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67308239/670028

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
\d+(\.\d+)+
```

`\d+`         : one or more digits
`\.`           : one point
`(\.\d+)+`   : one or more occurences of point-digits

Will find

```
2.5
3.4.567
3.4.567.001
```

But will not find

```
12
3.
.23
```

If you want to exclude decimal numbers like `2.5` and expect a version number to have at least 3 parts, you can use a quantifier like this

```
\d+(\.\d+){2,}
```

After the comma, you can specify a maximum number of ocurrences.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("\d+(\.\d+)+");
Match m = pattern.Match(a);
string version = m.Value;
```

Comment: That regex would also match dot-terminated numbers, such as `34.`.

Answer (score 7):

You can write

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$
```

This should match the format. The `$` is for matching at the end, can be dropped if not needed.

Comment: If the version number parts are separated with `_`, `\.` should be replaced with `_`: `[0-9]+(_[0-9]+)+$` (referring to [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56000605/3832970)).

Answer (score 3):

By version number, do you mean any sequence of digits interspersed with dots?

```
\d+(\.\d+)+
```