# Extract version from filename

Tags: c#, arrays, string

This is my sample filename `Text_2.23.txt` 
I already separated the extension but I'm not able to get the version out, so I could use it later in code for comparison.  I need to get `2.23` out,

edit: Filenames can be in various forms, but the version is allways at the end of the filename.

```
string s = f1.Name.ToString(); //for the Filename
int k = s.LastIndexOf('.');
string lhs = k < 0 ? s : s.Substring(0, k), 
    rhs = k < 0 ? "" : s.Substring(k + 1);

char[] array = lhs.ToCharArray();

Array.Reverse(array);           // reverse search from right to left
for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
{   
    char letter = array[j];     //the letter I get out in the sample case is "3" 
}
```

Comment: Get it out as what? An `int`? And what kind of file format can you expect? (Otherwise you could just drop the `Text_` part)

Comment: Do the file name always come in the form `<Name>_<version>.<filetype>`?

Comment: You can't have 2.23 as an int - you can have 2 or 3 if you want a single int - or 2 and 23 if you want two separate ints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Path` and `Version` classes:

```
string fileName = "Text_2.23.txt";
string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
string[] parts = fn.Split('_');

Version v;
if (parts.Length > 1 && Version.TryParse(parts.Last(), out v))
{
    Console.Write("Major:{0}, Minor:{1}", v.Major, v.Minor);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/YFe2mj)

**Edit**: since you have commented that your file-names could be almost arbitrary, but the version is always at the end and you just want that `string`.

With your commented samples:

```
string[] fileNames = new[] { "teext_023.ext", "txtxt.x9.08.ext", "text0911.ext" };
string[] versions = fileNames
    .Select(fileName =>
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Split('_')
            .Last()
            .Reverse()
            .TakeWhile(c => c == '.' || Char.IsDigit(c))
            .Reverse()
    ).Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray())).ToArray();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ElPztq)

Comment: I'd suggest you might want to use `.LastOrDefault()` and check for null to ensure handle cases when the filename does not have an underscore `_` character

Comment: I was concerned that a there may be multiple underscores eg. `My_file_2.23.txt`.  As you say `Split('_').LastOrDefault()` does not check null input nor input with no underscore.

But I think now we've suggested the types of input checking and exceptions that might be important - I'm happy that the OP can decide based on what the expected/allowable input is and what the acceptable failure modes are...

Comment: It's a small possibility, but there could be a filename with more digits. That is why I need to check character after character from right to left until i get to a non digit character

Comment: @Grhm: My final approach with `Last` but only if there's a separator at all.  @ anzes: Could you provide a sample?

Comment: These are all the various filenames that I can expect: teext_023.ext, txtxt.x9.08.ext, text0911.ext and I need to get version in x.xx | (1.02) format out.

Comment: @anzes: Please provide a sample since i don't understand what you mean with "there could be a filename with more digits". A `Version` follows this pattern: `major.minor[.build[.revision]]` (the two last are optional). Each version part is `int` in the whole range of `int`. **EDIT** to be honest, your file names don't seem to follow a strict rule. What generated these filenames? There's no separator, no real file name, no valid version number, looks almost arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, the don't follow, that's why I was thinking about checking the characters from right to left until some non digit. The only character that is allowed is one/single dot '.'

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for, a simple way for solving my problem:

```
                Array.Reverse(array);  
                Boolean dot = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                {   
                    char letter = array[j];
                    if (char.IsNumber(letter))
                    {
                        version += letter.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (letter == '.')
                    {
                        if (dot)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        dot = true;
                    }
               }
                version = this.Reverse(version);

                if (version.Equals(""))
                {
                    version = "0";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few generic solutions using regular expressions (Regex) for extracting a version number from a string.

Explanation of the regular expression `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)`:

- `(` begins the 1st capture group
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)
- `)` closes the 1st capture group

So in the case of version numbers, which typically use the format `X.X.X.X`, it is just a matter of repeating the Regex pattern as many times as you need for the number of version number components you are interested in capturing.

1. The simplest yet least flexible solution is to look for the exact pattern you need. This method looks for a standard 4-component version number. To only look for a 2-part version number you would change the Regex to `(\d+\.\d+)`

```csharp
/// <summary>
/// Extracts a version from the given input.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">
/// String that may contain a valid 4-component version in the format X.X.X.X.
/// <para>
/// e.g. 1.0.0.0 or 0.0.17.95
/// </para>
/// </param>
/// <returns>Version or null.</returns>
public string ExtractVersionNumber(string input)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)");
    var match = regex.Match(input);
    return match.Success ? match.Value : null;
}
```

2. A more flexible solution is to specify whether you need the build and revision number components of a version number.

```csharp
/// <summary>
/// Extracts a version number from the given input.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">
/// String that may contain a valid version.
/// <para>
/// e.g. 1.0.0.0 or 0.0.17.95
/// </para>
/// </param>
/// <param name="requireBuild">
/// Indicates whether the build component of the version is required.
/// <para>
/// e.g. 1.0.0 or 0.0.17
/// </para>
/// </param>
/// <param name="requireRevision">
/// Indicates whether the revision component of the version is required.
/// <para>
/// e.g. 1.0.0.0 or 0.0.17.95
/// </para>
/// </param>
/// <returns>Version or null.</returns>
public string ExtractVersionNumber(string input, bool requireBuild = true, bool requireRevision = true)
{
    var pattern = @"\d+\.\d+";

    if (requireBuild)
    {
        pattern += @"\.\d+";
    }

    if (requireRevision)
    {
        pattern += @"\.\d+";
    }

    var regex = new Regex($"({pattern})");
    var match = regex.Match(input);
    return match.Success ? match.Value : null;
}
```

3. An alternative flexible approach is to specify the number of version number components required.

```csharp
/// <summary>
/// Extracts a version from the given input.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">
/// String that may contain a valid version number.
/// </param>
/// <param name="componentsRequired">
/// Number of version components required. Defaults to 4.
/// <para>Valid values: 4, 3, 2.</para>
/// <para>4 components example: 1.0.0.0 or 0.1.17.95</para>
/// <para>3 components example: 1.0.0   or 0.1.17</para>
/// <para>2 components example: 1.0     or 0.1</para>
/// </param>
/// <returns>Version or null.</returns>
public string ExtractVersionNumber(string input, int componentsRequired = 4)
{
    string pattern;
    switch (componentsRequired)
    {
        case 4:
            pattern = @"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)";
            break;
        case 3:
            pattern = @"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)";
            break;
        case 2:
            pattern = @"(\d+\.\d+)";
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(componentsRequired), "Valid values: 4, 3, 2");
        }

    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var match = regex.Match(input);
    return match.Success ? match.Value : null;
}
```