# Extract version number from string(eg : "ver.1.9.0")

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

if i pass a string (verstring == "vername.1.19.5") it will return the version because i am ignoring Currentver[0]. if i want to pass verstring == "1.19.5".

I mean i will get verstring in both formats with version name(vername) or only version(1.19.5)

```
    public VerInfo(string verString)
    {
        string[] currentVer;

        if (versionString.Contains("."))
            currentVer= versionString.Split(".".ToCharArray());
        else
            currentVer= versionString.Split(":".ToCharArray());

        a= Convert.ToByte(currentVer[1]);
        b= Convert.ToByte(currentVer[2]);
        c= Convert.ToByte(currentVer[3]);
    }
```

Comment: How can the numbers  vary? Is it always 3? Separated by : and . ?

Comment: You don't need regex. Replace the colon with dots and take a substring from index 5 until the end

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: number are always 3, separated by : or .

Comment: When asking a question about matching text, you must be very, very specific and clear about what is valid and what is invalid. [Small changes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42704239/revisions) can make a big difference in the correct answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67308239/670028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are opened to use `Regex`, the answer below might help you:

```cs
var regexPattern = @"(?:ver\:)?(?<major>\d)[\.|\:](?<minor>\d)[\.|\:](?<revision>\d)";
var regex = new Regex(regexPattern);

var match = regex.Match("1:2.3");
var major = Convert.ToByte(match.Groups["major"].Value);
var minor = Convert.ToByte(match.Groups["minor"].Value);
var revision = Convert.ToByte(match.Groups["revision"].Value);
```

It uses regex named groups in order to retrieve the value versions. You can change the group name as part of the regex by a,b,c if you prefer and you would get something like this:

```cs
var regexPattern = @"(?:ver\:)?(?<a>\d)[\.|\:](?<b>\d)[\.|\:](?<c>\d)";
var regex = new Regex(regexPattern);

var match = regex.Match("1:2.3");
var a = Convert.ToByte(match.Groups["a"].Value);
var b = Convert.ToByte(match.Groups["b"].Value);
var c = Convert.ToByte(match.Groups["c"].Value);
```

Comment: this failed to parse 2.7.14, returned 2.7.1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegVer {
    class Prog {
        static void Main() {
            var verstring = "ver:1:9.5";
            var dotVerString = verstring.Replace(':','.');
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(dotVerString, @"ver\.([\d\.]+)").Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want array with each version digit.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegVer {
    class Prog {
        static void Main() {
            var verstring = "ver:1:9.5";
            var VerABC = Regex.Matches(verstring, @"\d");
            Console.WriteLine("a = " + VerABC[0] + "\n" +
                              "b = " + VerABC[1] + "\n" +
                              "c = " + VerABC[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why making life harder as it already is?

```
string v = verstring.Replace(':','.').Substring(5,verstring.Length);
```

Now you don't need to care about whether it actually is separated by `:` or `.` you can simply split by `.`:

```
currentVer = v.Split('.');
a= Convert.ToByte(currentVer[1]);
b= Convert.ToByte(currentVer[2]);
c= Convert.ToByte(currentVer[3]);
```