# Getting the last numbers from a string

Tags: c#

Hello I need to get last number from 1.0.0.0 but the number will change so eventually it can be 1.0.0.111

so I have stripped the number from "."

```
var amount = "1.0.0.23";
var pureAmount = amount.Replace(@".", "");
Console.WriteLine(pureAmount);
```

and then I have this extension method that returns the number

```
 public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static string GetLast(this string source, int tail_length)
        {
            if(tail_length >= source.Length)
                return source;
            return source.Substring(source.Length - tail_length);
        }
    }
```

used like this

```
Console.WriteLine(amount.GetLast(1));
```

But what if I don't know how many digits will the last number have? I just need the number behind the last "." is there a way to do the?

Comment: Maybe instead of removing all the dots, you should **split** your string and here you have the number you are looking for, ready to use

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955657/regex-pattern-to-extract-version-number-from-string

Comment: `amount.Split(new[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last()`

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using single statement. Try string functions `Split` and `Last`

```
var result = amount.Split('.').Last();
```

Comment: Guess it's because the question is a trivial duplicate. I mean, if the exact same content  is already available in the do you mean Keat target TH-PB then this one isn't useful, right?

Comment: Not my downvote but it should say '.' not "." I think.

Comment: Another suggestion is to use the version class: var result = new Version(source).MinorRevision.ToString();

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you should really check to make sure that your code compiles *before* you post it as an answer.  I see that you've since fixed your code (editing the parameter to `string.Split` so that it's a `char` and not a `string`), but ...

Comment: it doesnt matter whether it is single quote or double quote.. its works in both

Comment: The overload of `string.Split` which takes a single string was [added in .NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_). Some people aren't aware it exists yet

Comment: It's also inefficient. `LastIndexOf()` would have been better